# Crawl some of Javascript codes in a web-page

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, web-scraping

The page I am trying to crawl has includes javascript code. (Possibly using AJAX?) When I crawl the page based on the html code, it can't get the javascript part. How can I do that?

I think I need some libraries in python which can crawl the javascript code including html codes.

Please give me some advice.

Below is the page link: 
view-source:http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=652691&tbl=cyber

Comment: Do a Google on web scraping. It's a whole world of its own. There are various tools out there to help you along, including Casper, Phantom, Selenium, Scrapy to name a few. Some assembly required.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikkel.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two ways.

First, request ajax url directly and parse HTML.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/proc/mycar_regist_option.php"
data = {'param': 'ALL'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
# parse
...
```

Second, use `web driver`, like geckodriver, phantomjs and so on, using `selenium` library.

That library make virtual browser, run javascript and then render the DOM made by javascript.

[This](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is public documents about `selenium`

Comment: yumere, I deeply appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.